# Fail to run Compare-Object in Windows 10

Tags: windows, powershell, compareobject

I´m trying to run Compare-Object for a mounted ISO. These 3 lines works perfect with v 4.0 in Windows 8.1.

```
$Driveletters = (Get-Volume).Driveletter
$SetupDriveLetter = (Mount-DiskImage -ImagePath "Mypath")
$ISODriveletter = (Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $DriveLetters -DifferenceObject (Get-Volume).DriveLetter).InputObject
```

When I run the same lines in Windows 10, I´m presented with the following error.
What am I doing wrong? Does anyone has any suggestions I would really appreciate it.

Compare-Object : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'ReferenceObject' because it is null.
At line:1 char:55
+ ... ODriveletter = (Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $DriveLetters -Differ ...
+                                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Compare-Object], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CompareObjectCommand

Comment: Do you have any volume without drive letter?

Comment: Unfortunately not, good tip though. Have tried this on several Windows 10 machines with the same result.

Comment: @KristofferEkenhammar Are you absolutely sure? Does `$DriveLetters.Count` match the number of drive letters listed when you issue `"$DriveLetters"` at the prompt? I'm having a hard time believing you don't have at least one driveletter-less system reserved partition

Comment: Sorry guys, you´re absolutley right, I do have letter-less reserved partitions. Ok, so I really don´t understand why that would affect me. The thing I want to do is to get my driveletters, mount the ISO and then compare what changes has been made. Why does letter-less drives prohibits that? Just running '$Driveletters' with a return gives me C, but '$Driveletters.Count' returns 3. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Thanks for the help, ended up using another way. Sorry for bugging you. 
$ISO = 'mypath'
Mount-DiskImage -ImagePath $ISO -StorageType ISO

$ISODriveLetter = (Get-DiskImage -ImagePath $ISO | Get-Volume).DriveLetter
Write-Host ("ISO Drive should be " + $ISODriveLetter) 

seems to work now.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen how do you specify code in the comments section?

Comment: Backticks surrounding your snip :-)

Answer (score 1):

As determined in the comments, your `$DriveLetters` array contains at least one `$null`-value item. You can filter away items with no value using `Where-Object`:

```
$DriveLetters = (Get-Volume).DriveLetter |Where-Object { $_ }
```